# Matching my form string with condition in database in php?

Tags: php, forms

This is coming from my form field :

```
$subject="physics with maths";
```

This is in my database :

```
$keywordsindatabse="(physics && electronics) || (electronics & communication) || (electronics and communication)";
```

On submission of form I  want to match the condition `$keywordsindatabse` with `$subject`.
Any Ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Code:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
<select name="sselect"  id="itmn">

                        <option value="">Select</option>

            <option value='1'>1</option>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                        <option value='5'>5</option>
                        <option value='6'>6</option>
                        <option value='7'>7</option>            
          </select>
<input  type='text' name='gmajorsub' id=""" value="" onblur="chkdegree(document.getElementById('itmn').value,this.value);">
</form>

<script>
 function chkdegree(item_id,keyword)
 {


 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "degree_match.php",
            dataType: 'html',
        data: {item_id : item_id,keyword : keyword},
            success: function(data){
                if(data=="0")
        {
         alert("Dear Applicant, You are not allowed to register.You Subject not matching our essential qualification requirements.");
                  document.getElementById("gmajorsub").value="";
                  document.getElementById("gmajorsub").focus();
                  return false;
        }
            }
    });
 }

</script>
```

degree_match.php:

```
<?php
include("../../lib/dbc/dbConnection.php");
require('../../lib/dbc/commonFunc.php');
require('../../lib/dbc/dbHandler.class.php');
$dbObject = new dbHandler();
$dbObject->connect();
$query="select * from advt_110_post_details where recNo='".$_REQUEST['item_id']."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$keyword=strtolower($_REQUEST['keyword']);

$degree=$num['subject_keywords'];

$degree1=explode("|",$degree);





$max = array(null, 0); // category, occurences
/*foreach($degree1 as $k => $v) {
  $replaced = str_replace($v, '##########', $keyword);
  preg_match_all('/##########/i', $replaced, $matches);
  if(count($matches[0]) > $max[1]) {
    $max[0] = $k;
    $max[1] = count($matches[0]);
  }
}


if($max[1]>=count($degree1))
{
  echo"1";  
}
else{
    echo"0";
}
*/
/*foreach($degree1 as $k => $v) {

if ( strstr( $membership, "member" ) )
{

}

}
*/

?>
```

Comment: Can you be mote specific? What do you want exactly  and what have you tried (actual code would help)

Answer (score 0):

Note: You're code is subject ot SQL injection. Look at using PDO prepared statements or mySQLi prepared statements. At the very least, wrap string input into hte database in mysql_real_escape_string.

---

Looking at your code, you're getting items from a database and then filtering. I'm assuming mySQL.

You might be better doing this withing the database end. Check out "[full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)". This only works with MyISAM tables, so change that if needed. Then add a FullText index to the table on the 'subject_keywords' and you'll need to set up a boolean seaerch using full text. Details on the [boolean search are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

(Failing that, Rishi's answer above has introduced the loops you need - that was missing from your attempt.)

Answer (score -1):

As far as i understood from your post, the below code might help..

```
$subject="physics with maths";
$keywordsindatabse="(physics && electronics) ||
(electronics & communication) ||
(electronics and communication)";
$pieces = explode(" ", $subject);
$piecesDB = explode("||", $keywordsindatabse);
$subsDBv=array();
foreach($piecesDB as $key=>$subsDB){
    $subsDBv[$key] = str_replace(array("(",")"),"",explode(" ", $subsDB));
    }
foreach($subsDBv as $subslvd){
foreach($subslvd as $subslv){
    $ao = next($subslvd);
foreach($pieces as $subs){
if((strpos($subslv,$subs) !== false) AND (strpos($ao,$subs) !== false)){
    echo "Match found..<br />"; 
    }
    else{       
        echo "Sorry, no match found..<br />";
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: $subject is not fixed , it will be filled by user...also we need to check it according to condition provided as ('physics' in ($subject) && 'electronics' in ($subject)) || ('electronics' in ($subject) && 'communication' in ($subject) ) etc.